# How I can prevent bower from downloading the whole repo

Tags: javascript, yeoman, bower, bower-install

I just need the .min files, but it downloads the whole repo and it's very big.

This is my bower.json

```
{
"name": "blah",
"version": "0.0.0",
"dependencies": {
    "backbone": "~1.0.0",
    "underscore": "~1.4.4",
    "jquery": "~1.9.1",
    "backbone.localStorage": "~1.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "",
    "requirejs": "",
    "mustache": "",
    "hammerjs": ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bower is deliberately not opinionated about the content of packages, so it does not give you that kind of control, it just downloads the whole thing.

The idea is that you would then use a build system or task runner (such as [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/)) to perform tasks like minification or compilation as a second step.