# Bower: download DataTables Plugin for bootstrap integration

Tags: datatables, bower

Basic question about bower and dataTables. I would like to use bower to download the dataTables plugin for bootstrap 3 integration.
(I've already tested the page with the cdn links and everything works... now I'd like to use bower).

Here is the reference page on DataTables site:
https://datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap

As you can see these are the cdn links:
http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/3cfcc339e89/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.css

http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/3cfcc339e89/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.js

And here is the Github Repository:
https://github.com/DataTables/Plugins/tree/master/integration/bootstrap

NOTE: The root of the github repo contains many plugins; I just want the two files (js and css) for the bootstrap integration.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Actually, you can install a package with all DataTables plugins using the following bower command:

```
bower install datatables-plugins
```

DataTables Boostrap CSS will be on integration folder.

Answer (score 12):

**Update: please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31158954/896265) answer.**

I came here via Google trying to work out how to install the DataTables Bootstrap integration plugin via Bower, as `bower install datatables` does not include the repo for DataTables plugins. I found my answer [here](https://github.com/DataTables/Plugins/issues/86): the Bootstrap integration plugin for DataTables is only available via CDN or from the DataTables site. No official Bower package exists which includes the integration plugins.

Comment: Appreciated!! Thank you very much for sharing the link. +1 added.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes Possible** and Here is [Offical Page](https://www.datatables.net/download/bower)

**SOLUTION 1**

**SHORTCUT** replace this file and run `bower install` **DONE!**

here is bower.json for datatable

```
 {
  "name": "Project Name",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "~2.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.6",
    "datatables.net-bs": "~1.10.10",
    "datatables-autofill-bootstrap": "datatables.net-autofill-bs#~2.1.0",
    "datatables.net-buttons-bs": "~1.1.1",
    "datatables.net-colreorder-bs": "~1.3.0",
    "datatables.net-fixedcolumns-bs": "~3.2.0",
    "datatables.net-fixedheader-bs": "~3.1.0",
    "datatables.net-keytable-bs": "~2.1.0",
    "datatables.net-responsive-bs": "~2.0.1",
    "datatables.net-scroller-bs": "~1.4.0",
    "datatables.net-select-bs": "~1.1.0"
  }
}
```

**SOLUTION 2:**

Datatable itself

```
bower install --save datatables.net
```

OPTION

```
bower install --save datatables.net-dt //datatables
bower install --save datatables.net-bs //Bootstrap  //bs Same for all...
bower install --save datatables.net-zf //Foundation //zf Same for all...
bower install --save datatables.net-jqui //JQUERY //jqui Same for all...
```

**AND EXTENSIONS**

**AutoFill**

```
bower install --save datatables.net-autofill
bower install --save datatables.net-autofill-dt
```

**Buttons**

```
bower install --save datatables.net-buttons
bower install --save datatables.net-buttons-dt
```

**ColReorder**

```
bower install --save datatables.net-colreorder
bower install --save datatables.net-colreorder-dt
```

**FixedColumns**

```
bower install --save datatables.net-fixedcolumns
bower install --save datatables.net-fixedcolumns-dt
```

**FixedHeader**

```
bower install --save datatables.net-fixedheader
bower install --save datatables.net-fixedheader-dt
```

**KeyTable**

```
bower install --save datatables.net-keytable
bower install --save datatables.net-keytable-dt
```

**Responsive**

```
bower install --save datatables.net-responsive
bower install --save datatables.net-responsive-dt
```

**Scroller**

```
bower install --save datatables.net-scroller
bower install --save datatables.net-scroller-dt
```

**Select**

```
bower install --save datatables.net-select
bower install --save datatables.net-select-dt
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually when you execute

```
bower install datatables
```

you can find the bootstrap js at

```
/media/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Bower is a great package manager for the Web, but it's not possible to my knowledge to get only two file in repository with it.

With bower you recover the entire github repository. And after you include only the files you wants.

Take place on pc but don't change anything in webapp (in terms of space).

Comment: See this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22988599/how-i-can-prevent-bower-from-downloading-the-whole-repo

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, you have the correct bower packages. Don't use the *datatables* package, but instead use the *datatables.net* package: `bower install datatables.net`

You'll see that you have a specific package for each datatables plugin and for each theme framework (bootstrap, etc.) You just have to use the packages prefixed with **datatables.net**. **The packages are from the official Datatables developer.**

Checkout the available packages at http://bower.io/search/?q=datatables.net